# MS Word 2007 Randomly Saves a blank doc

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-office

Got a user that everyone once in awhile (maybe once every 2 weeks or so) will do a "save as" in their Word 2007 and the created, saved document will be blank. But most of the time, "save as" works fine. Already re-installed the whole Office Suite.

It's fine when he does email attachments. This is not related to email.

Sequence of events (from client):

1. I create a new document and select SAVE AS
2. I select a file to SAVE AS
3. I create a name ie.  ExampleFileA
4. I select SAVE
5. A blank document is what is saved
6. I can sometimes recover the content of the document by selecting RECENT DOCUMENTS
7. Yesterday, the file for ExampleFileA in RECENT DOCUMENTS was blank
8. The situation has occurred with both pre-existing and newly created documents

Any thoughts?

Comment: And that's what I did =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your domain password, this worked.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't think there is a solution to your problem because it looks like Word just fails saving your documents in a randomly fasion due to the technical issue that user cannot fix. I would suggest to plan re-installing Windows on that machine. It could turn out that re-installing Windows and several applications is faster that the time you could spend figuring out the reason why Word fails.